# convert dict of lists of tuples to dataframe

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe, tuples

I have a dict of lists of tuples of the form:

```
{identifier1:[(date1,value1),
              (date2,value2)],
 identifier2:[(date1,value1),
              (date3,value3),
              (date4,value4)]
}
```

I'm trying to parse this into a dataframe but the lists are of different lengths and the tuples have duplicate values. The shape I want is three columns identifier, date and value where there are no nan values. I have tried various combinations such as using `from_dict` method with very little success.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use list comprehension with `DataFrame` constructor (`python 3`):

```
d = {'identifier1':[('date1','value1'),('date2','value2')],
     'identifier2':[('date1','value1'),('date3','value3'),('date4','value4')]}

L = [(k, *t) for k, v in d.items() for t in v]

df = pd.DataFrame(L, columns=['identifier','date','val'])
print (df)
    identifier   date     val
0  identifier1  date1  value1
1  identifier1  date2  value2
2  identifier2  date1  value1
3  identifier2  date3  value3
4  identifier2  date4  value4
```

---

For `python 2` use:

```
L = [(k, t[0], t[1]) for k, v in d.items() for t in v]

df = pd.DataFrame(L, columns=['identifier','date','val'])
print (df)
    identifier   date     val
0  identifier1  date1  value1
1  identifier1  date2  value2
2  identifier2  date1  value1
3  identifier2  date3  value3
4  identifier2  date4  value4
```

Comment: I think yes. I add solution for python 2 too.