# Create dataframe from rows which comprise differing column names

Tags: pandas, dataframe

(Question rewritten as per comment-suggestions)

Suppose I have data like this:

```
{
    2012: [ ('A', 9), ('C', 7), ('D', 4) ],
    2013: [ ('B', 7), ('C', 6), ('E', 1) ]
}
```

How would I construct a dataframe that will account for the 'missing columns' in the rows?

i.e.

```
  year A B C D E
0 2012 9 0 7 4 0
1 2013 0 7 6 0 1
```

I suppose I can perform a trivial preliminary manipulation to get:

```
[
    [ ('year', 2012), ('A', 9), ('C', 7), ('D', 4) ],
    [ ('year', 2013), ('B', 7), ('C', 6), ('E', 1) ]
]
```

Comment: How the output should look like ?... A snapshot please

Comment: What have you tried until now? Please post sample usable data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first apply the method suggested in this [`post`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45915104/18470692) by [`@jezrael`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2901002/jezrael), create a `df` with the standard constructor, and then use [`df.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) to get the `df` in the desired shape:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    2012: [ ('A', 9), ('C', 7), ('D', 4) ],
    2013: [ ('B', 7), ('C', 6), ('E', 1) ]
}

L = [(k, *t) for k, v in data.items() for t in v]

df = pd.DataFrame(L).rename(columns={0:'year'})\
    .pivot(index='year', columns=1, values=2).fillna(0).reset_index(drop=False)
df.columns.name = None

print(df)

   year    A    B    C    D    E
0  2012  9.0  0.0  7.0  4.0  0.0
1  2013  0.0  7.0  6.0  0.0  1.0
```

If the values are all `ints`, you could do `.fillna(0).astype(int).reset_index(drop=False)`, of course.

Answer (score -1):

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    2012: [ ('A', 9), ('C', 7), ('D', 4) ],
    2013: [ ('B', 7), ('C', 6), ('E', 1) ]
}

L = [(k, *t) for k, v in data.items() for t in v]

df = pd.DataFrame(L).rename(columns={0:'year'})\
    .pivot(index='year', columns=1, values=2).fillna(0).reset_index(drop=False)
df.columns.name = None

df = df.astype({'A':'int','B':'int','C':'int','D':'int','E':'int'})
```

Comment: that would be *exactly* the same (minus the unnecessarily complicated `astype` method) as the answer I already provided half an hour ago...